# Winodow not appearing in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this code is in referrence to a cricket scoring program

When a button is pressed in my program, it runs a validation based of the users input and if it goes through, it should open a new window. But every time I run the code, the window.

```
def team_names(team):
    global team_amount
    global team_name_input
    global team_amount_test
    team_name_input = Toplevel(master)
    confirm_screen.withdraw()
    enter_names = Label(team_name_input, text = "Enter amount of players in " + team).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    enter_names2 = Label(team_name_input, text="(Between 2 and 11)").grid(row=1, column=1)
    team_amount_test = Entry(team_name_input, width = 20)
    team_amount_test.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    submit_amount = Button(team_name_input, text="Submit", command= lambda:amount_validation(team_1_array)).grid(row=3, column=1) <--- Button to open new winodw
    

def amount_validation(team_array):
    team_num = 1
    team_amount = int(team_amount_test.get())
    if team_num == 1:
        current_team = team_1
    elif team_num == 2:
        current_team = team_2
        
        
        #Validation
    if team_amount < 2 or team_amount > 11:
        error = Label(team_name_input, text = "Invalid amount, try again").grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    elif team_amount > 2 or team_amount < 11:
        player_num = 1
        name_input_win = Toplevel(master) #Should open new winodw here
        #name_input_win.geometry("200x150")
        team_name_input.withdraw()
        first = Label(name_input_win, text = "Enter player " + str(player_num) + " for " + str(current_team)).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        name_input = Entry(name_input_win)
        name_input.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        name = str(name_input.get())
        for i in range(0, player_num):
            p = None
        while not p or p in team_array:
            #first = Label(name_input, text="Enter player " + str(player_num) + " for " + str(current_team)).grid(row=0,column=1)
            if p in team_array:
                error = Label(name_input, text = "Player already entered").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        team_array.append(p)
        player_num = player_num + 1
```

Any help will be appriciated ^-^

Comment: Nothing in your example ever calls `team_names`. Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: You called `team_name_input.withdraw()`, so the window is not visible.